# Loading an image sequence in InterfaceBuilder -ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

Using Actionscript and or in the Flash IDE you can either instantiate bitmaps from the library, or simply import bitmaps into the timeline of a MovieClip to create an image sequence.

How would you do the same thing in InterfaceBuilder and-or using ObjectiveC? Do I need to create a new view for each and every image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store them in an array.
Something like so:

```
NSMutableArray *_imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];   //or you can alloc-init if needed
UIImage *_firstImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *_secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rambo.png"];
etc...

[_imageArray addObject:_firstImage];
[_imageArray addObject:_secondImage];
```

And then go through them in a NSTimer loop or something similar.
Hope it helps